# How do I remove focus from a button, so that pushing the spacebar or Enter doesn't trigger the button?

Tags: windows-runtime

When you click or tap a button, it gives it focus, so that when you push the spacebar or Enter, it triggers the button again. I don't want that to happen.
I tried this: `button1.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Unfocused);`
But the unwanted behavior still happens (pushing the spacebar or Enter triggers the button again). I also tried setting focus to another button using the Programmatic and Keyboard FocusStates but that doesn't fix it either.

Any help, especially an explanation of why this is happening, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the TabStop property to False, but be aware that doing this disallows user from using the button by keyboard.

```
 <Button Content="Click Me By Pointer!" IsTabStop="False"/>
```

**Update**

As [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702161.aspx) states:

> You can't remove focus from a control by calling this method with FocusState.Unfocused as the parameter. This value is not allowed and causes an exception. To remove focus from a control, set focus to a different control.

So another way to achieve this, is setting focus to previously focused element when the button is about to get focus by pointer. Unfortunatly the [GettingFocus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.gettingfocus.aspx) event is not working for the Button class (maybe because final version is not released yet?) so we should use GotFocus event, it's ugly it but works.

```
bool moveFocus = false;
public MainPage() {
    this.InitializeComponent();            
}
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    if (moveFocus) {
        UIElement focusedElement = FocusManager.FindNextFocusableElement(FocusNavigationDirection.Right);
        if (focusedElement is Control) {
            ((Control)focusedElement).Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
        }
    }
}
private void Button_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    moveFocus = (button.FocusState == FocusState.Pointer);
}
```

Note that I passed FocusNavigationDirection.Right to [FocusManager.FindNextFocusableElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn895335.aspx) to get an element in right, I should have used FocusNavigationDirection.Previous instead to get previous element but it returns null for unknown reason.

Comment: Thanks for the response... is that the only option?

Comment: @OwenD. check the updated answer, but I still suggest the first option.